# The fastest approach to inserting big data collections to Cassandra in C#

Tags: c#, performance, cassandra, batch-insert

I'm a little bit confused about the fastest way to insert large collections to cassandra database. I read that I shouldn't use batch insert because it's created for atomicity. Even Cassandra thow an information for me to use asynchronic writes for performace.
I've used code for the fastest insert without 'batch' keyword:

```
var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
 .AddContactPoint(“127.0.0.1")
 .Build();
 var session = cluster.Connect();

 //Save off the prepared statement you’re going to use
 var statement = session.Prepare (“INSERT INTO tester.users (userID, firstName, lastName) VALUES (?,?,?)”);

 var tasks = new List<Task>();
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
 {

 //please bind with whatever actually useful data you’re importing
 var bind = statement.Bind (i, “John”, “Tester”);
 var resultSetFuture = session.ExecuteAsync (bind);
 tasks.Add (resultSetFuture);
 }

 Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
 cluster.Shutdown();
```

from: https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e 
But it's still much slower than batch option i'm using. My current code looks like this:

```
IList<Movie> moviesList = Movie.CreateMoviesCollectionForCassandra(collectionEntriesNumber);
            var preparedStatements = new List<PreparedStatement>();
            foreach (var statement in preparedStatements)
            {
                statement.SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.One);
            }
            var statementBinding = new BatchStatement();
            statementBinding.SetBatchType(BatchType.Unlogged);

        for (int i = 0; i < collectionEntriesNumber; i++)
        {
            preparedStatements.Add(Session.Prepare("INSERT INTO Movies (id, title, description, year, genres, rating, originallanguage, productioncountry, votingsnumber, director) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < collectionEntriesNumber; i++)
        {
            statementBinding.Add(preparedStatements[i].Bind(moviesList[i].Id, moviesList[i].Title,
                moviesList[i].Description, moviesList[i].Year, moviesList[i].Genres, moviesList[i].Rating,
                moviesList[i].OriginalLanguage, moviesList[i].ProductionCountry, moviesList[i].VotingsNumber,
                new Director(moviesList[0].Director.Id, moviesList[i].Director.Firstname,
                    moviesList[i].Director.Lastname, moviesList[i].Director.Age)));
        }
        watch.Start();
        Session.ExecuteAsync(statementBinding);
        watch.Stop();
```

It really works much much faster but i can only insert ~2500 prepared statements, no more, and I want to measure time of about 100000 objects insertion.

Is my code correct? Maybe I just should increase insert treshold?
Please, explain my how to do it right way.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you should prepare your once and reuse that same `PreparedStatement` to bind to different parameters.

You can use small sized batches if you are targeting the same partition, if not you should use individual requests.

When using individual requests, you can schedule executions in parallel and limit the amount of outstanding requests using a semaphore.

Something like:

```
    public async Task<long> Execute(
        IStatement[] statements, int parallelism, int maxOutstandingRequests)
    {
        var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxOutstandingRequests);
        var tasks = new Task<RowSet>[statements.Length];
        var chunkSize = statements.Length / parallelism;
        if (chunkSize == 0)
        {
            chunkSize = 1;
        }
        var statementLength = statements.Length;
        var launchTasks = new Task[parallelism + 1];
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < parallelism + 1; i++)
        {
            var startIndex = i * chunkSize;
            //start to launch in parallel
            launchTasks[i] = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < chunkSize; j++)
                {
                    var index = startIndex + j;
                    if (index >= statementLength)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                    var t = _session.ExecuteAsync(statements[index]);
                    tasks[index] = t;
                    var rs = await t;
                    semaphore.Release();
                }
            });
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(launchTasks);
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        watch.Stop();
        return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
```

Comment: How about increasing default batch size? I have one table with primary key(ID)